# SQL Server searching by criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this result set

[image]

What logic would help where by the results should appear only if the criteria below has been satisfied?

If the user passes in TagID 3 then `Low` and `Low, Medium` appears.

if the user passes in TagID 4, only `Low, Medium` appears

If the users passes in TagID 3 AND 4, only `Low, Medium` appears.

I have this so far but I am struggling about the logic for the last sentence

```
    @List AS dbo.ReportingItemIDList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT RI.ID, ItemContent,
    FROM dbo.ReportingItem RI
    JOIN dbo.ItemTag IT ON IT.ReportingItemID = RI.ID
    JOIN @List ON IT.TagID = [@List].ID
```

Any advice ( doesnt need to be answer as such) would be useful

Comment: What's your input value look like?

Comment: Its an array of Ints basically, so the user can choose, 3, 4, or 3 and 4, any combination. @D-Shih

Comment: I didn't understand what did you want, try to improve your question please

Answer (score 1):

So you want the `itemscontent` common to all tags.

```
select itemscontent
from resultset
where tagid in (3, 4)
group by itemscontent
having count(*) = 2;  -- 2 is the number of tags
```